# refrescar consulta ajax para grafica

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, apex-chart

tengo el siguiente problema. Al cargar la página me aparece esta gráifca full funcionando [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando quiero cambiar el año, que lo ando realizando por un select me sale de esta manera y no me reinicia la página

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero realizar es que me cargue normal la grafica si escojo 2022. Empiezo a compartir código

```
<script>
    var base_url = "<?= base_url() ?>";
   // Aqui traigo el año y envio a la funcion del ajax a consultar

    $('#year').on('change',function(e) {
        var year = $(this).val();
        datagrafico2(base_url, year);
        // $('#chart2').load();
    });
    $('#year').trigger('change');

// aqui envio el ajax para consultar en lado servidor y traer un json
    function datagrafico2(base_url, year) {
        namesMonth = ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"];
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "Reportes/getData?id=<?= $inversion->id ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                year: year
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                var dias = new Array();
                var ganancia = new Array();
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    dias.push(namesMonth[value.mes - 1]);
                    valor = Number(value.ganancia).toFixed(4) * 100;
                    ganancia.push(valor);
                });
                grafica(dias, ganancia).reset();
            }
        });
    }

 // Aqui ya empieza a graficar con apexchart
    function grafica(dias, ganancia) {

        var options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar',

            },
            series: [{
                name: 'ganancia %',
                data: ganancia 
            }],

            stroke: {
                show: true,
                width: 3
            },

            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    columnWidth: '90%',
                    distributed: true,
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
                labels: {
                    rotate: -45
                },
                categories: dias,
                tickPlacement: 'on'
            },
            yaxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Mes',
                },
            },
        }

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart2"), options);

        chart.render();
    }
</script>
```

No creo necesario incluir el lado del servidor, ya que si me está trayendo los datos. Solo necesito que me reinicie la gráfica reemplazandola con la ya creada

Answer (score 2):

Primero podrías eliminar el anterior chart y posteriormente volver a crearla, así:

```
var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart2"), options);
try {
  chart.destroy();
}
catch { }
var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart2"), options);
chart.render();
```

Comment: me funciona solo si hay un minimo cambio en la relación de pantalla. Abro el menú de inspeccionar y me carga. Vuelvo a cambiar la fecha y reduzco un punto en la relación de aspecto y me muestra los datos que son. La idea es que me recarga al instante